# Use of undeclared type 'Observable'

Tags: rx-swift

Xcode:10
Swift:4.2

*******Use of undeclared type 'Observable'*******

I use this code, msg : Use of undeclared type 'Observable'
how to solve?

```
func validateAccount(_ account: String) -> Observable<XDLoginRXModel>
```

---

this is my custom enum

```
import Foundation

enum XDLoginRXModel {
    case empty
    case ok(message: String)
    case failed(message: String)
}

extension XDLoginRXModel: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String{
        switch self {
        case .empty:
            return "Empty"
        case let .ok(message):
            return message
        case let .failed(message):
            return message
        }
    }
}

extension XDLoginRXModel {
    var isValid: Bool {
        switch self {
        case .ok:
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you importing RxSwift in the file where this function is declared? If no, add `import RxSwift` at the top of the file and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `import RxSwift` on top of the file.